# jquery DataTable fnAddData adding a white block in column header

Tags: jquery, datatables

When the following fnAddData function executes an extra block of white is added in the header and the checkbox is not aligned under the Select column header.
[image: Column White Space and offset checkbox]

```
var select = '<input type="checkbox" class="chkSelect" />';
var waive = '';
var ndex = tblOutstandingFees.fnAddData([select, waive, item.Year,
           item.Batch, item.FeeType, parseFloat(item.Amount).toFixed(2),
           (item.IsNSF.toString().toLowerCase() == 'true' ? 'Yes' : 'No')]);
var nTr = tblOutstandingFees.fnSettings().aoData[ndex[0]].nTr;
nTr.className = "row " + nTr.className;
```

Does anyone know what may cause this?  I have not changed the datatable css other than the blue background color for the header row.

```
.table thead > tr > th {
background: #428bca url("../images/light-blue-btn.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
border-color: #428bca;
color: #fff;
vertical-align: bottom;}
```

Oddly, if I have firebug open and go to inspect the element the white space goes away after clicking in the firebug html window.

This is only happening in Firefox v 45.0.2, works correctly in IE and Chrome

Comment: Can you try calling `tblOutstandingFees.fnAdjustColumnSizing()` after adding a row?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Can you please show your initialization code and HTML?